# Java generics lower bound

Tags: java, generics

I understand upper bound clearly, but don't fully understand lower bound. As for example I have this code:

```
public class Main<T> {
    private T t;

    public Main(T t) {
        this.t = t;
    }

    private static class Base {}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main<? super Base> main = new Main<>(new StringBuilder());
        System.out.println(main.t.getClass());
    }
}
```

Why there is no error during compile despite of `StringBuilder` isn't super class of `Base`. As I thought it would be illegal to provide type which is irrelevant (I know that it's impossible to assign non child class to `t` after type inference). Also it works with collections, does it means that collection could possibly store no child, no super class of `Base`? Please do not link me to PECS questions, I have read them a lot.

Comment: You have to write your Main class as public class Main<T extends Base>

Comment: I think `<T>` here is Object, which is a legal super type of both Base and String.  The way you are doing this / thinking about this is flawed, basically.  Check out the answer to this question (ignore the duplicate text for PECS): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343202/difference-between-super-t-and-extends-t-in-java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:** I saw it a little late that **@markspace's answer** is nearly the same and was posted before this. I am only retaining this here due different styles of explanation, that is all.

---

This should be due to the diamond operator `<>` due to which automatic inference happens based on the most possible route, in this case the constructor parameter.

I could not locate the official description of the diamond operator, but various sources describe it to the effect - the Java compiler does a type inference when given the diamond operator feature determines **the most suitable constructor declaration** that matches the invocation.

If you change your declaration to `GenericsSuper<? super Base> main = new GenericsSuper<StringBuilder>(new StringBuilder())` you will get your expected error.

Without this explicit declaration, `<>` leads to `<Object>` due to the `super` restriction, and consequently anything is allowed, because:

- The code in `GenericsSuper` has no problem with `StringBuilder`. It just wants `T`.
- `Base` has a common super with `StringBuilder` in `Object`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to add this as an actual answer.

I think `<T>` here is Object, which is a legal super type of both Base and StringBuilder. The way you are doing this / thinking about this is flawed, basically. Check out the answer to this question (ignore the duplicate text for PECS):

[Difference between <? super T> and <? extends T> in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343202/difference-between-super-t-and-extends-t-in-java)

Notice the examples that the accepted answer gives, especially the one with `<Object>`:

```
List<? super Integer> foo3 = new ArrayList<Integer>();  // Integer is a "superclass" of Integer (in this context)
List<? super Integer> foo3 = new ArrayList<Number>();   // Number is a superclass of Integer
List<? super Integer> foo3 = new ArrayList<Object>();   // Object is a superclass of Integer
```

Since you're allowing the diamond operator to "figure out" the type of `T`, it "figures out" that `Object` works and uses that.  Untested, but check if this also compiles:

```
Main<? super Base> main = new Main<Object>(new StringBuilder());
```

Comment: As I though but I don't know how to check actual generic type at runtime, despite generics are erasure types there are some ways to obtain actual type at runtime, but they didn't help.